# How to enable "live search" in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, search, komodoedit

In [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit), an input field is available in the toolbar. When I type text in it, it highlights matching search results. Is there something like this in Eclipse, either directly or via a plugin?

Answer (score 14):

As TK Gospodinov has already [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8921000/545027), there is an *Incremental* option in **Find/Replace (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)** dialog.

There is also a special key binding for Incremental search in Eclipse (and personally I use it more frequently). From Eclipse [Tips and Tricks](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tips/platform_tips.html#Editing):

> Use **Edit > Incremental Find Next (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>)** or **Edit > Incremental Find Previous (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>)** to enter the incremental find mode, and start typing the string to match. Matches are found incrementally as you type. The search string is shown in the status line. Press **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>** or **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>** to go to the next or previous match. Press **<kbd>Enter</kbd>** or **<kbd>Esc</kbd>** to exit incremental find mode.

Comment: You can also use up arrow/ down arrow to navigate once you enter incremental find mode

Answer (score 5):

If you'd like to have search functionality in a toolbar, you may be interested in the [eclipse-glance plugin](http://code.google.com/p/eclipse-glance/), which allows you to use the incremental search function in a toolbar by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> while in any text area.

Comment: Looks nice. Just installed it. :)

Comment: Yes, it does come in handy. Now if only they could get a nicer implementation for the Find/Replace dialog... ;-)

Answer (score 4):

This feature is already available in eclipse. No need to install any plug-in.
Press `Ctrl+F`, and the Find pop up appears.

[image]

Now check the incremental checkbox, and then your texts will be found as you type. No need to hit return.

OR

Use `Ctrl+J` and you can activate the live search, just that there wont be any UI visible, but you can see the status in eclipse status bar at the bottom.

Press `Ctrl+J`, start typing the text you want to search for. Press `esc` to go back to edit mode

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to the functionality you are asking about is the 'incremental search' mode, which is triggered by checking the 'Incremental' checkbox in the Options group on the Find/Replace dialog in Eclipse (Ctrl+F from the code editor). This will make it start highlighting matches as you type, and if they are keywords, Eclipse will highlight other occurrences (references) in the code editor. Matches inside strings or Javadoc will not be highlighted, however, unless it happens to be the first match after your cursor's position inside the editor.

Answer (score 0):

One similar thing (not the same) is just enabling "mark occurences", then selecting function name, variable etc.