# eclipse IDE search in open file (triggered by Ctrl-F) triggers an intrusive popup

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

The search in open file feature (triggered by Ctrl-F) triggers an intrusive popup like so;

[image]

But ive been using Aptana studio, and I see this UI style as having the dialog flush to the editor frame;

[image]

and that seems a bit nicer.

Is thare something that is available natively via configuration, or is that going to require some custom hacking of the new plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I just wanted to recommend <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd> (incremental search, without any GUI) the question [How to enable "live search" in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710725/how-to-enable-live-search-in-eclipse) has even more alternatives for you, with [Eclipse Glance](http://code.google.com/p/eclipse-glance/) matching your request the most.

Comment: I found a couple of plug-ins from the marketplace with "find bar" which has not been returned with "search plugins" and variations. But the incremental search probably does the job. Thanks.